# Given a morphism from X to Y, when is the morphism from O_Y to the pushforward of O_X injective 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, locally-ringed-spaces, schemes

I would like to know under what condition the morphism $\mathcal{O}_Y\longrightarrow f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X$ induced by a morphism $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ of schemes is injective.

Let me give an example (which I'm not completely sure about though).

I believe, if $X$ and $Y$ are reduced and $f$ is surjective and closed, the morphism $\mathcal{O}_Y \longrightarrow f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X$ is injective.

(Thus, proper flat morphisms of varieties have this property.)

Maybe one could forget about schemes and give a condition for locally ringed spaces?

Comment: Dear @Ariyan Javanpeykar, Eléments de Géométrie Algébrique I (Springer, 1971) Proposition 5.4.3 (p.284) may help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f$ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated then the kernel of the map $O_Y\to f_*(O_X)$ consists of locally nilpotent elements if and only if $f(X)\subset Y$ is a dense set.

Answer (score 5):

This is the condition of $f$ being scheme-theoretically dominant.  (If $f$ satisfies the closely related condition considered in LRG's answer, of having dense image, one says that $f$ is dominant.)
These conditions are discussed very carefully in the stacks project.  (Google "stacks project" if you don't know the link already.)  (Also, the precise definitions may involve finiteness conditions that I am omitting here; the stacks project write-up will have complete details.)

Comment: The best reference for this question I have found is Grothendieck, EGA, I, 9.5.